# Laravel Localhost no muestra pagina principal, solo corchetes [ ]

Tags: php, laravel, localhost, artisan

Al iniciar el servidor con el comando php artisan serve inicia correctamente pero al ir al navegador no muestra nada mas que dos corchetes: " [] " como se ve en la imagen. https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWfQf.png

Luego si en la url le agrego /login o alguna otra url de alguna ruta ingresa correctamente. De un dia para el otro aparecio este problema.

Mi archivo de rutas web.php:

```
 //Pantalla Principal==============================
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
//================================================

//Autenticacion===================================
Auth::routes();
//================================================

//ADMIN panel=====================================
Route::get('/home',function(){
  return view('admin.layout');
});
```

Comment: que tienes en tu vista welcome?

Comment: Tengo un backgorund image, una imagen y un titulo. Nada más

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En algún lado tienes un

> **dd();**

Intenta ir desde tu archivo de rutas -> middlewares -> Controllers -> (si se aplica) -> estrategies -> Repositories -> vistas.

Lo mas seguro es que tengas dentro de la función dd un array vacio.

Por cierto para debuguear código es mala practica utilizarlos.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, ya encontré lo que pasaba, una de las ultimas  lineas de rutas no tenia una url, estaba de la forma: Route::get('','controller@function) etc etc.. . Siempre usé dd( ); para debug, como lo haces vos?

Comment: Utilizo debug de visual studio code.

Answer (score 0):

Si no has cambiano nada en los middleware, ni has cambiado la ruta de las vistas prueba refrescando el contenido de los siguientes recursos:

Desde tu entorno de trabajo abre un terminal y tipea los siguiente comandos

1) Limpiar el cache

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

2) Limpiar las rutas

```
php artisan route:cache
```

3) Limpiar el archivo de configuracion

```
php artisan config:clear
```

4) Limpiar las vistas

```
php artisan view:clear
```

Comment: Lo intenté pero nada por ahora. Estoy revisando las rutas y las vistas ahora a ver que encuentro.

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré el error, una linea de las rutas no tenia una URL asignada:

```
Route::get('','CarreraController@ListarMateriasPorCarrera')->name('ListarMateriasPorCarrera')->middleware('auth');
```

Lo cambié a:

```
Route::get('/condicionfinal','CarreraController@ListarMateriasPorCarrera')->name('ListarMateriasPorCarrera')->middleware('auth');
```

Y todo funcionó correctamente!